# strange characters (amp;) added to moss service output

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, moss

I have moss service which output the url of image.

Lets say the output url has '&' character , the service appending amp; next to &.

for ex: Directory.aspx?&z=BWxNK

Here amp; is additionally added. it is a moss sevice. so i don't have control on the sevice.

what i can do is decode the output. As i am using Ajax calls for calling moss sevice i am forced to decode the out put from javascript. i tried decodeURIComponent,decodeURI,unescape. nothing solved the problem.

Any help greatly appreciated. even server side function also helpful. i am using Aspl.net MVC3

Regards,
Kumar.

Comment: `&amp;` is an url encoded replacement of `&`. Nothing strange about that. You need to url-decode

Comment: @Topener — No it isn't. `%26` is a URL encoded replacement for `&`! `&amp;` is SGML encoded (and derivatives such as HTML and XML).

Comment: @Quentin ah right. My bad. I tend to confuse these things ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&amp;` is not URI encoded, it's HTML encoded.

For a server side solution, you could do this:

```
Server.HtmlDecode("&amp;") // yields "&"
```

For a JavaScript solution, you could set the *html* to `"&amp;"` and read out the *text*, to simulate HTML decoding. In jQuery, it could look like this:

```
$("<span/>").html("&amp;").text(); // yields "&"
```

Comment: Tahnks David, it worked like a charm. can i call didrectly the html function without temporary span element.

Comment: No, what you're doing in that piece of code is to set the HTML content of the temporary span that you're creating (but never adding to the document), so you really do need some placeholder variable to add the HTML to, from which you can then read the text.

Answer (score 0):

`&amp;` is SGML/XML/HTML for `&`.

If the service is outputting an XML document, then make sure you are using an XML parser to parse it (and not regular expressions or something equally crazy).

Otherwise, you need decode the (presumably) HTML. In JavaScript, the easiest way to do that is:

```
var foo = document.createElement('div');
foo.innerHTML = myString;
var url = foo.firstChild.data;
```